# Bar.setBarStyle(BarStyle.RECTGRADIENT) does not work as intended

Tags: java, android, teechart

The gradient is erroneously painted using `StartColor` and `Color`. It does not respect the value of `EndColor`.

```
Bar bar = new Bar();
bar.setMultiBar(MultiBars.STACKED);
bar.setBarStyle(BarStyle.RECTGRADIENT);
bar.getGradient().setDirection(GradientDirection.VERTICAL);
bar.getGradient().setUseMiddle(false);

bar.getGradient().setStartColor(Color.fromArgb(0xff000000));
bar.getGradient().setEndColor(Color.fromArgb(0xffffff00));

// WORKAROUND: Setting the color yields a valid gradient.
// bar.setColor(Color.fromArgb(0xffffff00));
```

Android 4.1.2, Nexus S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. I've added it to the defect list to be revised for next releases.
In the meanwhile, the workaround you suggested looks fine to me.